# Passing Form Values into a controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

say I have a text field like the following in a view called 'search':

```
 <%= text_field_tag(:lookup) %>
```

how do I submit this ':lookup' value and pass it into the controller called 'search' and assign it to a variable?

It's a basic problem, but being a noob, it's difficult ;)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That will be accessible in the controller as

```
params[:lookup]
```

Your controller could look something like this:

```
class SearchesController < ActionController::Base

  def search
    lookup = params[:lookup]
    @models = Model.find_by_lookup(lookup)
  end
end
```

And your view should look like this:

```
<%= form_tag searches_path do %>
  <label for="lookup">Lookup</label>
  <%= text_field_tag :lookup %>
 <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in the question, but how do I submit the form?

Comment: arrg I must be stupid today. 
Am I supposed to create a controller file called searches_controller.rb?

Comment: Yes. If you're just getting started using scaffolding as an example might help. http://fairleads.blogspot.com/2007/12/rails-20-and-scaffolding-step-by-step.html

Comment: Don't forget the equals sign before form_tag so that the form actually shows up!
`<%= form_tag searches_path do %>`